# What is the keyboard shortcut ctrl+option+shift+power for?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I'm running a MacBook Pro Retina (Mid 2014) with macOS High Sierra (10.13.3).

Coincidentally, I found the key combination <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>+<kbd>Option ⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>+<kbd>Power button</kbd> that immediately turns the MacBook off. As soon as I press the buttons, the screen is black and the computer is off. It's like a kill switch.

What is that shortcut for and how is it called? Does it hurt my computer?

EDIT: Maybe it is related to the SMC Reset? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the apple support: This key combination resets the SMC ([System Management Controller](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)). The SMC takes control of the battery. Once the controller has been reset, the power supply is cut off.
It is not recommended to do this while the Mac is turned on.

Comment: the commands for resetting the smc vary between some of the models - is this a universal command or just for one model - yours?

Comment: This keyboard shortcut is for MacBooks with nonremovable batteries only.